# Trouble expanding container DIV

Tags: html, css

There's a demo here > http://jsfiddle.net/AndyMP/4hzXe/

I can't figure out why the container DIV isn't expanding.

CSS

```
#container { 
position: relative;
width: 400px;
border: solid 1px #333;
padding: 20px;
}
#left { 
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border: 1px solid blue;
margin: 10px;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">

<div id="left"></div>
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="left"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: because the innder divs are floating...if you want to achieve the effect of having the divs appear on the same line, try putting display:inline; into #left.

Comment: Avoid having the same id for multiple elements. Make "left" a class...

Comment: I updated to use clear: both which works, but is there a nicer way of doing it? http://jsfiddle.net/AndyMP/4hzXe/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear the floats. http://jsfiddle.net/4hzXe/2/

added the line `overflow: hidden;`, you can use [clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/). I use the clearfix solution most of the time

```
#container { /* Preview content box */
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    border: solid 1px #333;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I also changed the `id="left"` to a `class="left"`, id should only appear once on a page.

Comment: Known support: Firefox 3.5+, Safari 4+, Chrome, Opera 9+, IE 6+

Answer (score 1):

You need a technique to contain your floats. At least two possibilities:

1. [Containing floats with floats](http://jsfiddle.net/4hzXe/4/)
2. [Enclose floats with clear](http://jsfiddle.net/4hzXe/5/)

Which method is best for you? (my recommendation)

1. If you have an element (e.g. hr) that can take on the job of clearing, use it.
2. If it is possible to set the parent's width, use the float property in conjunction with a width (**that's your case**).
3. Use Easyclearing otherwise
4. Use the overflow property in situations that are straightforward

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
.left { 
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    margin: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

`<div id="left"></div>` changed to `<div class="left"></div>`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4hzXe/6/